# Two simultaneous Hotspot connections between two devices

Tags: tethering

I just discovered you can create two simultaneous Hotspot connections from a single Mac to an iPhone: one via USB and one via Wi-Fi.

Why is this allowed/possible? Are there any advantages/disadvantages to doing this?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

It's the same as with a router that you connect to via ethernet and WiFi. OS X will rely on the services in the oder which has been specified in system preferences > network. The upside is that if one link goes down you still have the other (continue surfing when you plug out the iPhone without the interruption of needing to get an IP first etc.)